# Can mongoDB be embedded in a Java program?

Tags: java, mongodb, database, nosql

Can MongoDb be embedded in a Java program?

If it can't be embedded, is there any NoSQL database that can be embedded?

By embedded I mean packaged with a Java app so that a user will not need to set up a database, just install and start using.

Comment: It seems duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115637/can-mongodb-be-used-as-an-embedded-database

Comment: I disagree with the duplicate. It is slightly different enough in dealing with a specific language, Java, and asking for alternatives that it deserves to stand on its own.  Now if someone would just look at this question ... that is an entirely different story.