# Free Embedded Only Document Database For Commercial Use

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, document-database

I'm looking at document databases for my ASP.NET MVC application, and I need something that I can embed into my application, but is also free.  I have a public web site that I'm not making money off yet, but may in the future.  That said, I noticed the following about these servers:

- RavenDB not free for commercial use in embedded form
- MongoDB free, but not natively embeddable.  Some have gotten it to embed, but it may require AGPL licensing, which I can't do if this is true ([Can mongodb be used as an embedded database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115637/can-mongodb-be-used-as-an-embedded-database)).
- db40 not free for commercial use where the source isn't generally available.

Is there any out there that are fast and free?  Again, I CANNOT host it as a server, but need an embeddable database into the application.

Thanks.

Comment: RavenDB do suggest getting in contact with them for free licensing if you are a start up, if that helps.

Comment: I'm looking for the same solution... Have you found any answers?

Comment: @NelsonReis The only thing I found is that it's possible, with some modification, to make MongoDB run in embedded form.  Debating whether I want to try that.