# Embedded MongoDB instance?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, nosql

I've been using MongoDB for a little tool that I'm building, but I have two problems that I don't know if I can "solve". Those problems are mainly related with having to start a MongoDB server (mongod).

The first is that I have to run two commands every time that I want to use it (mongod and my app's command) and the other is testing. For now, I'm using different collections for "production" and "test", but it would be better to have just an embedded / self-contained instance that I can start and drop whenever I want.

Is that possible? Or should I just use something else, like SQLite for that?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can mongodb be used as an embedded database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115637/can-mongodb-be-used-as-an-embedded-database)

Comment: @maerics Thank you! I tried to find something here, but couldn't. So maybe there's no good way of doing that yet. I'll look for alternatives.

Comment: MongoDB isn't designed to be run embedded. But you can fake it by making your application create a mongod child process which operates on a local --dbpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use this at work - https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/embedmongo.flapdoodle.de - to fire up embedded Mongo for integration tests.  Has worked really well.

Comment: Hi - have you used it for Ruby projects? I've used it in Java projects before and came across this question as I was looking for a Ruby equivalent. If you've had any luck with Ruby, I'd really appreciate seeing how you went about it.

Answer (score 2):

Another similar project is https://github.com/Softmotions/ejdb. 
The query syntax is similar to mongodb.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it, but I just found this Ruby implementation of an embedded MongoDB: https://github.com/gdb/embedded-mongo

Comment: This project seems rather dead. Last commit was a year ago, and it still misses a lot.

Comment: I have confirmed that embedded-mongo no longer works with ruby mongo 1.12.5 and since that version is a major behind already I can't imagine it will work with the current mongo versions.