# Embedded mongodb in camel service

Tags: mongodb, apache-camel

Is there a way we can use embedded `mongodb` in `camel` peoject. I know there is `camel-mongodb`. But I couldn't find any example of using embed `mongodb`. db should be able to use throughout the camel service life time.

Comment: Just to clear this up, what you want is a persisted connection for the service or a connection pool from which to draw from over the service, or services lifecycle. Is that correct?

Comment: yes. I want to start a db instance with camel service and end when service removed. but I don't want to desperately host a db.

Comment: I think you meant "separately host"

Comment: @NeilLunn oh! yep don't want **separatly** host

Comment: Take a look at these:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6437226/embedded-mongodb-when-running-integration-tests

Answer (score 0):

Camel is java, but you can't really embed native applications without serious efforts. Even technical issues put aside, you will have to worry about struggle with the license (AGPL). I'd say the answer is no.

See the following SO
[MongoDB embedded in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19565861/mongodb-embedded-in-java)