# Embedded data store for java application?

Tags: mongodb, jakarta-ee, ldap, embed, datastore

I am creating simple authentication server that will store user and password and user groups in database.

I want to provide simple embedded data store to manage user/passwords and groups.

What will be suitable:

1. LDAP server data store
2. mongodb datastore by storing values against each user names etc
3. Any other?

It should also have some java api to store and retrieve data .

Please suggest?

Answer (score 0):

I think for your case MongoDB will be good.It is fast to access vias API provided by mongoDB.Use Hibernate OGM.But as you want embeded then mongoDB will not be a good choice.However you can try this http://www.project-voldemort.com/voldemort/

Embedded Server

You can instantiate the server directly in your code.

```
VoldemortConfig config = VoldemortConfig.loadFromEnvironmentVariable();
VoldemortServer server = new VoldemortServer(config);
server.start();
```

For this you first need to include jar in your environment variable classpath or by including volemart jar inside your project classpath

Comment: But this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115637/can-mongodb-be-used-as-an-embedded-database say we cant use mongoDB as embedded in java applications. It has to be  different instance.

Comment: If you want embeded the you can finf it helpful.  http://www.project-voldemort.com/voldemort/

Comment: if i use hsql db, is that db in memory . I mean on restart of my aplication i want to reload saved data?

Comment: Can voldemort persist data to disk? if i restart server i dont want to lose my old data.

Comment: Yes it does.Just try it out with some in basic java program and all the things got clear.